# Rewrite attribute in - struct nl_msg - message (netlink, libnl)

Tags: linux, ipc, netlink

The `libnl` library provides functions like `nla_put_...(...)` for adding attributes to a netlink message. Can I somehow rewrite certain attribute without recreating the whole message? Didn't found any interface function in `libnl` fot doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you mean overwrite the attribute value?

Comment: @Vencat yes, i mean overwrite the value without changing attribute's type

Comment: what happens if you call the same function again with the same message, same attribute but with a different value? 
for example, 
nla_put_u8(msg, ATTR_INT, 2);
nla_put_u8(msg, ATTR_INT, 4); // now it's overwritten isn't it ?

Comment: @Vencat no, this function simply allocates memory and writes attribute header and value. It doesn’t check if attribute already exists. Check the source code